# marquee property to scroll text left right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, marquee

what property in marquee tag that allows me to scroll the marquee content continuously ? If I have 5 items as its content, I would like to separate space equally for all 5 items, AND also for the space between the 5th of one scroll and the first of the next roll.

Because normally the marquee will finish all items before it starts the next scroll but the last item and the first item are separated more than each item present in the marquee content, in my case.

For example, 1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5 etc
each "-" is the space and time divided equally for items in the marquee. Thank you

Comment: `<marquee>` like `<blink>` is a proprietary tag and is best avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loop` attribute is what you are looking for with a value of `-1` means scroll continuously. You can find more information from the [Mozilla Developer Network Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee).

I feel I should warn you up front that the `marquee` tag is not a standard tag and will render differently in all browsers.  Many attributes are not supported cross browser.  You my want to find a suitable jQuery plugin to handle cross browser for you.  If you are doing something simple then the marquee tag may work for you, though I wouldn't advocate it.

As for width, you can put each item in a container such as a `div` tag then add appropriate margin as fit as such:

```
<marquee>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</marquee>
```

If you'd like to be more "syntactically correct" You might use a `ul` with `li` tags

```
<marquee>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
     </ul>
</marquee>
```

More html/css but grouped a little more logically for screen readers and print purposes.

Comment: Thank you but the waiting time I have to endure between the second and the first items whenthe first scroll is being finished is still long and it displays blank space between 2-1 in (1-2-1-2-1-2...). I would like all are treated as separate items in equal time and space during srolls

Comment: You could use jQuery to clone the contents of the marquee and stack it multiple times, or look to using a jQuery plugin, but as is that is one of the major limitations of using marquee by itself.

Comment: could you offer a sample pleas ?

Comment: Google is your friend here.  A quick google search for `jquery marquee plugin` gets you what you're after.